# BufferedReader in pylucne

Tags: lucene, pylucene

I am using pylucne to build a search system. I am using TREC data to test my system. I have successfully written the indexer and searcher code. Now I want to use TREC topics to evaluate my system. To do this there is a class named [`TrecTopicsReader()`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/benchmark/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/quality/trec/TrecTopicsReader.html#readQueries%28java.io.BufferedReader%29) which reads the queries from the TREC formatted topics file. But `readQueries(BufferedReader reader)` of that class needs a `BufferedReader` topics file object passed to it.

How to do this in pylucene. BufferedReader is not available in pylucene JCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for some one to answer, I also asked this question on pylucene developer mailing list.
Andi Vajda  replied there. I am answering this question on Andi's behalf.

**Quoting Andi:**

> In the PyLucene Makefile find the jcc invocation and add java.io.BufferedReader to the long command line (don't forget the ending \ as needed) and rebuild PyLucene.

**More information:**
In the Makefile of pyLucene you will find this line `GENERATE=$(JCC) $(foreach jar,$(JARS),--jar $(jar)) \`. In this there should be a line like `--package java.io`, add the class(BufferedReader) you want to add to JCC so that it will be available to the python code.
Then compile and install the pylucene again. (You can find the info about compilation & installation at PyLucene's documentation or you can also use [this](http://john.wesorick.com/2011/11/installing-pylucene-on-ubuntu-1110.html)).

Also, for making a `BufferedReader` object from a file you will need `FileReader`. So add that also.

*Just for Completenes:* After adding this line my `GENERATE` will look like:

```
GENERATE=$(JCC) $(foreach jar,$(JARS),--jar $(jar)) \
           $(JCCFLAGS) --use_full_names \
           --package java.lang java.lang.System \
                               java.lang.Runtime \
           --package java.util java.util.Arrays \
                               java.util.Collections \
                               java.util.HashMap \
                               java.util.HashSet \
                               java.util.TreeSet \
                               java.lang.IllegalStateException \
                               java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException \
                               java.util.NoSuchElementException \
                     java.text.SimpleDateFormat \
                     java.text.DecimalFormat \
                     java.text.Collator \
           --package java.util.concurrent java.util.concurrent.Executors \
           --package java.util.regex \
           --package java.io java.io.StringReader \
                             java.io.InputStreamReader \
                             java.io.FileInputStream \
                             java.io.BufferedReader \
                             java.io.FileReader \
           --exclude org.apache.lucene.sandbox.queries.regex.JakartaRegexpCapabilities \
           --exclude org.apache.regexp.RegexpTunnel \
           --python lucene \
           --mapping org.apache.lucene.document.Document 'get:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;' \
           --mapping java.util.Properties 'getProperty:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;' \
           --sequence java.util.AbstractList 'size:()I' 'get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;' \
           org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter:getReader \
           --version $(LUCENE_VER) \
           --module python/collections.py \
           --module python/ICUNormalizer2Filter.py \
           --module python/ICUFoldingFilter.py \
           --module python/ICUTransformFilter.py \
           $(RESOURCES) \
           --files $(NUM_FILES)
```

*Doing this doesn't suffice, you also have to compile the lucene benchmark lib, which is not included in the installation libs by default, because `TrecTopicsReader` is present in benchmark api.*
To compile and install benchmark:
You have to modify the build.xml inside the main lucene folder, where the benchmark folder is present and then you have to include this jar in main Makefile to install it into python libs as egg.

**build.xml**:
You have to three modifications. For simplicity follow the `jar-test-framework` and wherever this is present try to create the similar pattern for `jar-benchmark`.

The three changes you have to do are:

*1)* `<target name="package" depends="jar-core, jar-test-framework, build-modules, init-dist, documentation"/>`  replace it with  `<target name="package" depends="jar-core, jar-test-framework, jar-benchmark, build-modules, init-dist, documentation"/>`

*2)* For the rule

```
  <target name="jar" depends="jar-core,jar-test-framework"
          description="Jars core, codecs, test-framework, and all modules">
    <modules-crawl target="jar-core"/>
  </target>
```

replace it with

```
  <target name="jar" depends="jar-core,jar-test-framework, jar-benchmark"
          description="Jars core, codecs, test-framework, and all modules">
    <modules-crawl target="jar-core"/>
  </target>
```

*3)* Add the following target/rule after the target named `jar-test-framework`

```
<target name="jar-benchmark">
    <ant dir="${common.dir}/benchmark" target="jar-core" inheritAll="false">
      <propertyset refid="uptodate.and.compiled.properties"/>
    </ant>
  </target>
```

**MakeFile**:
Here also you have to do three modifications. For simplicity follow `HIGHLIGHTER_JAR` and add similar rules for `BENCHMARK_JAR`. The three changes you have to are:

*1)* Find `JARS+=$(HIGHLIGHTER_JAR)` and add `JARS+=$(BENCHMARK_JAR)` after that in similar manner.

*2)* Find `HIGHLIGHTER_JAR=$(LUCENE)/build/highlighter/lucene-highlighter-$(LUCENE_VER).jar` and add `BENCHMARK_JAR=$(LUCENE)/build/benchmark/lucene-benchmark-$(LUCENE_VER).jar` after this line in similar manner.

*3)* Find the rule `$(ANALYZERS_JAR):` and another rule for `$(BENCHMARK_JAR):` after that.

```
$(BENCHMARK_JAR): $(LUCENE_JAR)
cd $(LUCENE)/benchmark; $(ANT) -Dversion=$(LUCENE_VER) compile
```

For completeness here are my final Mkaefile and build.xml files.